# Как разрешить конфликт двух скриптов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, разрешить конфликт двух скриптов. Первый скрипт работает успешно, если удаляю второй. Если второй скрипт добавляю, то первый перестает работать. В чем может быть конфликт? Вот рабочий пример: https://codepen.io/LADYX/pen/aWZPdE Благодарю!
Первый скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.navbar > ul > li.submenu > a').append('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
$('.toggleMenu').click(function(e){
$('.navbar > ul').slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('.submenu > ul > li').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.submenu').click(function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $('.navbar > ul > li').removeClass('active');
        $('.navbar > ul > li > ul').slideUp();
    }else{
        $('.navbar > ul > li').removeClass('active');
        $('.navbar > ul > li > ul').slideUp();
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).find('ul').stop().slideToggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    }
        $('.navbar > ul > li').removeClass('submenu_open');
        $(this).addClass('submenu_open');
});
$('body, html').click(function(){
    $('.navbar > ul > li').removeClass('active submenu_open');
    $('.navbar > ul > li > ul').slideUp(1);
});
});
```

Второй скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"], a[href^="."]').click( function(){
        var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top }, 500);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: html код можно ?

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" (Ctrl+M) для добавления кода. Сообщение должно быть самодостаточным, ссылки на Codepen и подобные ресурсы могут служить только дополнением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убираем `return false;` из второй функции и пишем `e.preventDefault();` все работает.

`href=#` ссылка-заглушка. При клике на нее произойдет перемещение на самый верх текущей страницы. Но, если использовать [`preventDefault`](https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action) - то действия браузера по умолчанию будут отменены и переброса вверх не будет.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navbar > ul > li.submenu > a').append('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');

  $('.toggleMenu').click(function(e) {
    //console.log('.toggleMenu');
    $('.navbar > ul').slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.submenu > ul > li').click(function(e) {
    //console.log('.submenu > ul > li');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('.submenu').click(function(e) {
    //console.log('.submenu');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $('.navbar > ul > li').removeClass('active');
      $('.navbar > ul > li > ul').slideUp();
    } else {
      $('.navbar > ul > li').removeClass('active');
      $('.navbar > ul > li > ul').slideUp();
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).find('ul').stop().slideToggle();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
    $('.navbar > ul > li').removeClass('submenu_open');
    $(this).addClass('submenu_open');
  });

  $('body, html').click(function() {
    //console.log('body, html');
    $('.navbar > ul > li').removeClass('active submenu_open');
    $('.navbar > ul > li > ul').slideUp(1);
  });

  $('a[href^="#"], a[href^="."]').click(function(e) {
    var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href');
    if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top
      }, 500);
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // вот так
  });

});
```

```css
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar :before,
.navbar :after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.navbar :after {
  clear: both;
}

.navbar>ul {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar>ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.navbar>ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.navbar>ul>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar>ul>li>ul {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar>ul>li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar>ul>li:hover,
.navbar>ul>.submenu.submenu_open {
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar>ul>li:hover a,
.navbar>ul>.submenu.submenu_open {
  color: #333;
}

.navbar .submenu-button {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.navbar .submenu-button::before,
.navbar .submenu-button::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #333;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar .submenu-button::before {
  top: 5px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 1px;
}

.navbar .submenu-button::after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 9px;
}

.navbar>ul>li:hover .submenu-button::before,
.navbar>ul>li:hover .submenu-button::after,
.navbar .active .submenu-button::before,
.navbar .active .submenu-button::after {
  background: #333;
}

.submenu.submenu_open a {
  color: #333;
}

.submenu_open .submenu-button::after,
.submenu_open .submenu-button::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.toggleMenu {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggleMenu::after,
.toggleMenu::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  width: 15px;
}

.toggleMenu::after {
  top: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000000;
}

.toggleMenu::before {
  top: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  border-top: 2px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

.submenu>ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.submenu>ul>li {
  float: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  position: relative;
}

.submenu>ul>li a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.submenu>ul>li a:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="toggleMenu">Меню</div>
  <ul>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Меню1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Меню11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Меню11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Меню11</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Меню2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Меню22</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Меню22</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Меню22</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Кстати, стоит отметить, что функция, определенная в пределах одного `$(document).ready` блока не может быть вызвана из другого `$(document).ready` блока. Никто не запрещает использовать несколько `$(document).ready` блоков, но это ухудшает читаемость кода, на мой взгляд. И еще одно - блоки будут выполнены по очереди, сверху вниз по коду.

Comment: @LADYX вместо `return false` пишите `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPbGJa

Comment: @zb', да-да, вы правы. Внес правку в ответ )

Comment: @LADYX, href=#  ссылка-заглушка. При клике на нее произойдет перемещение на самый верх текущей страницы. Но, если использовать `preventDefault` - то действия браузера по умолчанию будут отменены и переброса вверх не будет.